# Pole set of rational function on $V(WZ-XY)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $V = V(WZ - XY)\subset \mathbb{A}(k)^4$ (k is algebraically closed). This is an irreducible algebraic set so the coordinate ring is an integral domain which allows us to form a field of fractions, $k(V).$ Let $\overline{W}, \overline{X}$ denote the image of $W$ and $X$ in the coordinate ring. Let $f=\dfrac{\overline{W}}{\overline{X}}\in k(V).$ I want to find the pole set of $f.$ I have a feeling I am over complicating this. Essentially I should just view $f$ as the function $W/X$ restricted to $V.$ I know that points on $V$ where $X=0$ and $W\neq 0$ are in the pole set, and this occurs when $Z=0.$ But what happens if both $W$ and $X$ are $0$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the pole set of $f=\frac{\overline{W}}{\overline{X}}$ is precisely the set 
$$
S(f)=\{(w,0,y,0) \in \Bbb{A}^4 \; \vert \; w,y \in k\}=V(X,Z)
$$
It is clear that $f$ is defined at every point not in $S(f)$, because 
$$
f=\frac{\overline{W}}{\overline{X}}=\frac{\overline{Y}}{\overline{Z}}
$$
and from this you see that $f$ is defined at $(w,x,y,z)$ if either $x \neq 0$ or $z \neq 0$.

In order to see that $f$ is not defined anywhere else, let $P=(a,0,b,0) \in \Bbb{A}^4$, and assume you could write
$$
\frac{\overline{W}}{\overline{X}}=\frac{\overline{F}}{\overline{G}}
$$
with $F,G \in k[X,Y,Z,W]$ and $G(P) \neq 0$.

This implies that $G \cdot W-F \cdot X \in (WZ-XY)$, which means that $G \cdot W-F \cdot X=H \cdot (WZ-XY)$ for some $H \in k[X,Y,Z,W]$. Now you get
$$
X \cdot (F-HY)=W \cdot (G-HZ)
$$
from which it follows that $X$ must divide $G-HZ$, i.e. $G-HZ \in (X)$. But then evaluating at $P=(a,0,b,0)$ yields
$$
G(P)=0
$$
which contradicts our choice of $G$.

Comment: I haven't read the answer fully yet, but just first off: $f$ is in $k(V)$ - shouldn't the pole set of a rational function on $V$ be a subset of $V$ ?

Comment: @KatieDobbs: yes, it should and it is. Probably the confusion is due to my poor notation, which is different from the one used in the other answer. I wrote points in $\Bbb{A}^4$ as $(w,x,y,z)$, since I saw you using the same notation in the comment you left under the other answer. Otherwise, I would have written them as $(x,y,z,w)$. I can change to the latter, if you prefer.

Comment: Ahh no sorry, my mistake!! I had the crazy idea in my head that $V(X,Z)$ includes points outside of $V,$ which I just realized it does not!!

Answer (score 2):

By definition of pole set (e.g. Fulton's 'Algebraic Curves', sec 2.4, I'm guessing you have this book :) , we want to analyze: points $P\in V$ where $f$ is not defined, so these $P$ correspond to where $X=0$ *and* $Z=0$ which is $(X=0, Z=0)$ on $V$; note that we include $Z=0$ precisely because $\overline{W}/\overline{X} = \overline{Y}/\overline{Z} = f$ *in* $k(V)$. Thus, $$pole(f)_V = (X=0, Z=0) = \{(x,y,z,w): x=0, z=0\}.$$

What happens at $W=0$ or $Y=0$ is uninteresting here since we are interested in the *poles*, not *zeroes* of $f$

It's also helpful to think in terms of valuations, as in the Lemma following Prop 2 in sec 2.4 of Fulton.

As additional exercises, calculate the codimension of $pole(f)_V$ in $V$ and what is (geometrically and algebraically speaking) the intersection $pole(f)_V\cap pole(1/f)_V$?

Comment: I'm not sure why we need $Z=0$ for a pole. From the relation $\overline{W}/\overline{X}=\overline{Y}/\overline{Z} \in k(V)$ I can see why to be a pole you need both $\overline{X}=0$ and $\overline{Z}=0$ but I can't see it directly. For example, the point $(W,X,Y,Z) = (0,0,1,1)$ is on $V,$ $\overline{W}/\overline{X} = 0/0$ but $\overline{Y}/\overline{Z}=1/1=1.$

Comment: Your first sentence is false, as shown by the example in Katie's comment. Your second sentence is absurd : the definition of pole set desn't make us want to analyze anything . In that second sentence the relation $P\in k(V)$ is false too. Anyway, you have proved nothing about the actual question: Nils's correct answer shows that you have to make some actual calculations and get your hands dirty in order to answer the question instead of confining yourself to generalities, mentioning irrelevant valuations  and asking "supplementary exercises".

Comment: Why is it "absurd" to follow a definition in Fulton's book in order to study i.e. "analyze" an exercise that depends on the definition in question??

Comment: I've fixed the first sentence and now $P\in V$.